# MediaMetaDataRetriever.setDataSource return null

Tags: java, android, audio-streaming, internet-radio, mediametadataretriever

I'm trying to develop an application (**Radio Stream**) app, I want to get the details of the song that is playing on the radio for that **MediaMetadataRetriever API** but when i set my URL i get this error :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>                                                                              at
>   android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:71)
>                                                                              at
>   maa.myapp.MainActivity$PlayerTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:447)
>                                                                              at
>   maa.myapp.MainActivity$PlayerTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:419)

this my code :

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    String stream = "https://plaza.one/mp3";
    boolean prepared =false;
    boolean started =false ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AudioAttributes attribs = new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA).setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC).build();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(attribs);

        } else {
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        }


        new PlayerTask().execute(stream);
}
    public class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loadingRL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                prepared=true;
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return prepared;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
            super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

            /*get details : */
            MediaMetadataRetriever mMediaMetaDataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mMediaMetaDataRetriever.setDataSource(stream,new HashMap<String, String>());
            String titleName = mMediaMetaDataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Title : "+titleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a answer? If not please provide your full logcat

Comment: @H.Brooks `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Title : "+titleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` show me null : Title : null

Comment: What sdk are you testing on?

Comment: @H.Brooks minSdkVersion 15

Comment: There is no 'return null' here. There is an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @EJP I found the solution to my problem using this library   [audiostream-metadata-retriever](https://github.com/vsmaks/audiostream-metadata-retriever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally it work with **'com.vodyasov:amr:0.5'** library

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(stream);
            OnNewMetadataListener listener = new OnNewMetadataListener() {
                @Override
                public void onNewHeaders(String stringUri, List<String> name, List<String> desc, List<String> br, List<String> genre, List<String> info) {}
                @Override
                public void onNewStreamTitle(String stringUri, String streamTitle) {
                    songinfo.setText("Song Name : "+streamTitle);
                }
            };
            AudiostreamMetadataManager.getInstance()
                    .setUri(uri)
                    .setOnNewMetadataListener(listener)
                    .setUserAgent(UserAgent.WINDOWS_MEDIA_PLAYER)
                    .start();
```

Comment: How will a library fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14){
          mmr.setDataSource(stream, new HashMap<String, String>()); 
        }else {
          mmr.setDataSource(stream); 
        }

        String titleName = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Title : "+titleName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

If that doesn't work then you should make sure that the link you are using actually returns a file.

Try doing the above inside `onCreate`,  the problem could be something with your  AsyncTask.

Comment: my **minSdkVersion** is 15 so it's unnecessary to use`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=14` and still doens't wrok , but when i test my URL in VLC Media Player works fine so i don't think the problem in the URL

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code. Try a different link.

Comment: i try to use a different url like : http://94.23.43.135:8050/live.mp3 are actually return a file.mp3 and still doesn't work

Comment: i still get a title : NULL

Comment: Try getting the title of a song on the device like `metaRetriver.setDataSource("/sdcard/audio.mp3"); 
`